# "Error 7 (net::ERR_TIMED_OUT)" in chrome for local web app

Tags: asp.net, timeout, google-chrome

Since about two weeks (around when Google updated stable to version 26), our internal users began receiving periodical timeouts upon requesting pages within our locally hosted app (from Google Chrome). Specifically:

> This webpage is not available. Error 7 (net::ERR_TIMED_OUT): The operation timed out.

Our ASP.NET app never receives the HTTP request... In fact the issue seems nearly identical to "[Our app giving some Google Chrome users trouble :(](https://serverfault.com/questions/230782/our-app-giving-some-google-chrome-users-trouble)", except the error only appears sporadically throughout the day (~10 times per business day per user) and only for a few minutes at a time.

Here's the steps I've tried to troubleshoot with no luck:

1. Cleared cookies/cache
2. Removed all extensions
3. Re-installed chrome
4. Ran chrome with --disable-ssl-false-start (even though ["SSL False Start" has been disabled since version 20](http://www.imperialviolet.org/2012/04/11/falsestart.html))
5. Verified "Automatically detect settings" is NOT selected in "Settings > Advanced > Change Proxy Settings > LAN Settings"
6. Repro'd on Chrome Canary (version 27)

Here's the verbose log entry:

> [2552:1908:0306/154246:VERBOSE1:web_contents_impl.cc(2049)] Failed Provisional Load: http://grid.local/, error_code: -7, error_description: The operation timed out., is_main_frame: 1, showing_repost_interstitial: 0, frame_id: 1

Anybody have any other ideas to try?